# Android job scheduler periodic task is not working after sometime or after device restart

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am trying to execute a periodic task by using job scheduler . I want to call a service after each 10 second, it work fine for couple of hour but after sometimes it stops working and it doesn't work after device restart .

Here is what I have tried

```
ComponentName getAlertJobComponent = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GetAlertJobService.class.getName());
JobInfo.Builder getAlertbuilder = new JobInfo.Builder(Constants.getAlertJobid, getAlertJobComponent);
getAlertbuilder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY); // require unmetered network
getAlertbuilder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true); // device should be idle
getAlertbuilder.setPeriodic(10 * 1000);
getAlertbuilder.setRequiresCharging(false); // we don't care if the device is charging or not
JobScheduler getAlertjobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
getAlertjobScheduler.schedule(getAlertbuilder.build());
```

And my job sevice is

```
public class GetAlertJobService extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

        if (!Utility.isServiceRunning(GetAlertService.class, getApplicationContext())) {
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GetAlertService.class));
        }
        jobFinished(params, false);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here `GetAlertService` is service that is calling a web service

**EDIT**

I also added this on Boot receiver like following

```
 public class Boot extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ComponentName getAlertJobComponent = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GetAlertJobService.class.getName());
                JobInfo.Builder getAlertbuilder = new JobInfo.Builder(Constants.getAlertJobid, getAlertJobComponent);
                getAlertbuilder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY); // require unmetered network
                getAlertbuilder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true); // device should be idle
                getAlertbuilder.setPeriodic(10 * 1000);
                getAlertbuilder.setPersisted(true);
                getAlertbuilder.setRequiresCharging(false); // we don't care if the device is charging or not
                JobScheduler getAlertjobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                getAlertjobScheduler.schedule(getAlertbuilder.build());
            }
        }
    }
```

in manifest

```
<receiver
    android:name=".broadcastreceiver.Boot"
    android:enabled="true">

    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reset issue is solved by adding `setPersisted(true)` on the job builder.  For the stops working after a long time-  is the device asleep?  If so, its likely a doze issue.

Comment: yes, the device is asleep . If so how can I overcome this

Comment: You can't.  JobScheduler does not run under doze.  You could drop down to AlarmManager and use setExactAndAllowWhileIdle, but it still wouldn't allow you to wake anywhere near as frequently as you wish (there's a minimum period of IIRC 2 minutes between alarms, and a max number you can have in any 15 minute period).

Comment: Actually there is one thing you can do-  you can ask users to turn off battery optimizations for your app.  Its in that link I posted.

Comment: Please chek my edit I have also added this in boot receiver , is it ok ?

Comment: @GabeSechan Doze mode is understandable but after couple of hours when the device is awaked, still it doesn't work anymore after that

Comment: @SharpEdge, yes and what shall we do with it?

Comment: @AlexeySubbota I have switched to [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) for backward compatibility.. So far I've given up fighting Doze or Battery saver modes and show the user a message to disable it if they want "specific feature" to work properly..

Comment: @GabeSechan "You can't. JobScheduler does not run under doze", In doze device have the "windows" to do some necessary work and while window opened JobService would be executed.

Comment: @LifeStyle Yes, ever 15 minutes or so with exponential backoff.  Not every 10 seconds.